# Problem creating friendly SEO URLs on local server

Tags: apache, macos, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems implementing friendly SEO urls on my local (Mac OS X Snow Leopard) development server.

*Note: `site.com` is just an example

(1) Currently my site's root is set up with a virtual host pointing to a sub-directory of my Sites folder.

(2) Pages are currently being accessed in the following format: `http://site.com/index.php?page=login`

(3) I want to implement SEO as something like: `http://site.com/login`

(4) I've edited my personal apache configuration to include `AllowOverride All`

(5) I've created an .htaccess file called `site_com.htaccess` and placed it into the document root of site.com. The content of this file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).html /index.php?page=$1
```

(6) I've then restarted apache with `sudo apachectl restart`

What have I done wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the file from `site_com.htaccess` to simply `.htaccess`.

Comment: That doesn't do any thing. The browser complains about the url not being found.

Comment: @Tunji Well, for one thing your pattern expects `.html` at the end... Are you navigating to `/login` or `/login.html`?

Comment: lol, my mistake, silly me. login.html works. How would I achieve /login? Thanks.

Comment: @Tunji `RewriteRule ^(*)$ /index.php?page=$1`

Answer (score 1):

You're having problems applying your rewrite rules.

Use something like this:

```
// if not a file
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
// if not a directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
// pass all params back to index.php
// QSA stands for query string append
// L stands for last rule
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

**[And here is the manual for future reference! ;)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**